# decorating a function and adding functionalities preserving the number of argument

Tags: python, decorator

I'd like to decorate a function, using a pattern like this:

```
def deco(func):
    def wrap(*a,**kw):
        print "do something"
        return func(*a,**kw)
    return wrap
```

The problem is that if the function decorated has a prototype like that:

```
def function(a,b,c): return
```

When decorated, the prototype is destroyed by the varargs, for example, calling function(1,2,3,4) wouldn't result in an exception. Is that a way to avoid that?
How can define the wrap function with the same prototype as the decorated (func) one?

There's something conceptually wrong?

*EDIT*

My perverse idea was to lighten the "calling of the parent method" without modifying the signature. Something like

```
def __init__(self, something)
    super(ClassName, self).__init__(something)
```

to:

```
@extended
def __init__(self, something):
    ...
```

I was figuring out if this was possible and if this makes sense.

*EDIT*
As Alex pointed out, the following code doesn't give an exception:

```
function(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [decorator module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) helps you create a decorator that preserves the function signature.

As a result, you will get the exception you expect when calling the function, and `inspect.getargspec` will give you the correct signature.

It works by dynamically building a function definition and using `exec`. Unfortunately, there isn't an easier built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You're wrong when you state that "calling function(1,2,3,4) wouldn't result in an exception".  Check it out:

```
>>> def deco(f):
...   def w(*a, **k):
...     print 'do something'
...     return f(*a, **k)
...   return w
... 
>>> def f(a, b, c): return
... 
>>> f(1, 2, 3, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: f() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
>>> decorated = deco(f)
>>> decorated(1, 2, 3, 4)
do something
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in w
TypeError: f() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

As you see, you get exactly the same exception as when similarly calling the undecorated `f` (albeit after the `print` you've added).

For preserving the wrapped function's metadata (name, docstring, use [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.wraps#functools.wraps).  Predicting that the wrapped function will raise when called (to avoid doing other work before calling it) is always hard ("impossible" in general, as it's equivalent to the halting problem; "just hard" in specific, when you only care about raising a type-error for argument name and number mismatches and want to treat that specialized exception case differently from any other exception case -- a peculiar requirement;-0).

If you're adamant that you absolutely need it (and can perhaps explain *why*?) I'll be glad (well, not *glad*, but will grit my teeth and do it, after all I've got a long weekend in front of me;-) to take you down that labyrinthine path.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trick that involves fetching the original argument specification from the decorated function, then creating a lambda by evaling a string with the same arguments. The decorator is then wrapped in this lambda thus to the outside world it has the same parameter names and default values:

```
import inspect, time
import functools

def decorator_wrapper(old_function, new_function):
    args, arglist, kw, default = inspect.getargspec(old_function)
    args = list(args)

    if arglist:
       args.append(arglist)

    if kw:
       args.append(kw)

    callstring = inspect.formatargspec(args, arglist, kw, default, formatvalue=lambda value: "")
    argstring = inspect.formatargspec(args, arglist, kw, default)[1:-1]

    unique_name = "_func" + str(int(time.time()))
    codestring = "lambda " + argstring + " : " + unique_name + callstring
    decorated_function = eval(codestring, {unique_name: new_function})

    return functools.wraps(old_function)(decorated_function)
```

Comment: Clever, but insecure :(

Answer (score 0):

By calling `result=func(*a,**kw)` first, you get the TypeError before printing "do something".

```
def deco(func):
    def wrap(*a,**kw):
        result=func(*a,**kw)
        print "do something"
        return result
    return wrap

@deco
def function(a,b,c): return

function(1,2,3)
# do something
function(1,2,3,4)
# TypeError: function() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```